# Altering MSSQL view protected by RLS (SSDT) leads to an error during deployment

Tags: database, deployment, view, sql-server-data-tools, row-level-security

When adding a new column to a view protected by Row Level Security on Azure SQL Database, I get the following error when trying to publish the database using SQL Server Data Tools:

> Altering View [dbo].[vView]... (62,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data
> Provider: Msg 3729, Level 16, State 3, Procedure vView, Line 1 Cannot
> ALTER 'dbo.vView' because it is being referenced by object
> 'SecurityPolicy'. (62,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The
> executed script: ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vView] WITH SCHEMABINDING AS SELECT
> Id,
> [Name],
> 2 AS Number FROM   dbo.[Table];
>
> An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

I also tried to drop the security policy into a pre deployment script, the deployment was green, but no security police exists after the deployment. I guess delta script generation is created before pre deployment script.

I used

> Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.10.3
> VisualStudio.16.Release/16.10.3+31424.327 Microsoft .NET Framework
> Version 4.8.04084
>
> with
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.62106.24090 Microsoft SQL Server Data
> Tools

Any Idea how to solve this issue or is this a bug ?